# Public and private methods in Python

Tags: python, oop, stack, private, public

I am trying to change a public to private parameter inside a Python class. As far as I know, to make it private I need to declare for instance:

```
self.__top = None # <-- Instead of self.top = None
```

However, I cannot figure out how to make a private struct with private properties, such that they are called properly in the public methods.

For instance:

```
class Stack:

    def __init__(self, size=None):
        self.__top = None
        if size is None:  # if size is unset
            self.__size = -1
        else:
            self.__size = size
        self.__current_size = -1

    def push(self, data):
        if self.current_size >= self.size: # ERROR!
            print("Stack Overflow!")
            return
```

Comment: If you create an attribute `self.__size`, then it is `self.__size`, not `self.size`. The underscores are part of the name.

Comment: **Python does not have private attributes**. You are using double-underscore name-mangling, which is not the same thing as *private*. By convention, members that are not part of the public api are *prepended with a single underscore*. This is merely a *naming convention*. Double-underscore name-mangling is to prevent name-collisions in *subclasses*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that by using terms such as *struct*, *public* and *private* you must come from a background of [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)/[C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B). There are no such things in Python, and the naming of the attributes are purely conventional.

I recommend reading *[What is the meaning of a single and a double underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name)*.

Typically for your "private" attributes which you don't want for others to use outside of your class, the convention is to prefix it with a single underscore `_`, like `_size`. If you plan on using this outside, it boils down to these cases:

- do you want it to be writable from outside? In that case you just define it as `size` and use it like this everywhere
- do you want it to be read-only from outside? In this case you can make it private and make a property for it like:

Code:

```
class A:

    self __init__(self, size):
        self._size = size

    @property
    def size(self):
        return self._size
```

You also have the ability to translate the internal variable to another name, and make it writable at the same time under that different name.

Example:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, value):
        self._internal_var = value

    def set_data(self, value):
        self._internal_var = value

    def get_data(self):
        return self._internal_var

    data = property(get_data, set_data)
```

Or alternatively:

```
@property
def data(self):
    return self._internal_var

@data.setter
def data(self, value):
    self._internal_var = value
```

Then if you call

```
a1 = A(11)
print(a1.data)
a1.data = 22
print(a1.data)
```

it will yield:

```
11
22
```